# mvc action method doesn't recognize parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to set membership provider with confirmation email. `User` is successfully registrated using memb. provider.

After registration, a confirmation email is being sent with `userProviderKey` which is used to approve user. Link is sent as follows

```
http://localhost:48992/Account/Verify/e37df60d-b436-4b19-ac73-4343272e10e8
```

User must click on link sent with key (providerUserKey), problem that is this key does not even show in debug mode as parameter

```
// in debug providerUserKey is null
public ActionResult Verify(string providerUserKey)
{    
}
```

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the route configuration of Global.asax.cs file as :

```
          routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

You can see it has `id` parameter as optional. So if the querystring is recognized as `id` then it will have the value that you have passed.

Change the `id` to `providerUserKey` inorder to do the job for you.

```
      routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{providerUserKey}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index",providerUserKey=UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Or Keep the default optional parameter as `id` and pass `providerUserKey` as additional querystring parameter.

Say like this:

```
     @Html.Action("","",new { providerUserKey="e37df60d-b436-" })
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Unless you've specifed a rule in your global asax your url should look like

```
http://localhost:48992/Account/Verify?providerUserKey=e37df60d-b436-4b19-ac73-4343272e10e8
```

if you want to use the above format you need to map a new route in  your global.asax

```
routes.MapRoute(
    // Route name
    "routename",
    // Url with parameters
    "Account/Verify/{providerUserKey}/",
    // Parameter defaults
    new { controller = "Account", action = "Verify" }
    );
```

Comment: Slight bug in the query, no / after the verify

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the query to

```
http://localhost:48992/Account/Verify?providerUserKey=e37df60d-b436-4b19-ac73-4343272e10e8
```

Your `ActionResult` is looking for this parameter in the `URL`

Comment: Thanks thought it was a post request

Answer (score 1):

The Default MVC Route is {Controller}/{Action}/{Id}
Hence it recognize it if the parameter name is Id...

Change it to following and it will work.

```
public ActionResult Verify(string id)
        {    
        }
```

Still if you don't want to change the parameter name then you can add following routing in your global.asax file and it will work correctly.

```
routes.MapRoute("MyRouteName","{Controller}/{action}/{providerUserKey}")
```

You can also pass the default values to it if needed as your path is predefined.
Cheers